# Android/Xamarin.Android rest client timeout when switching network from wifi to 3g

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, network-programming, xamarin.forms

My team is using Xamarin forms (primarily targeting phones) to work on a project that relies on network connectivity. We are running into an issue on android that is inhibiting a major feature of our application. When we try and access a data service after switching from wifi to cellular, we will often receive timeout errors on the FIRST data retrieval attempt. Subsequent attempts work. **This problem DOES NOT occur the other way around (going from mobile to wifi)**. [This bug describes our problem, but says it's for iOS, and interestingly enough we dont get this issue on iOS](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23806).

A list of steps to reproduce is as follows:

1. Start the application on a phone using wifi
2. Attempt to retrieve data. This should result in a successful
   retrieval
3. Using the quick settings bar (pulling down from top of screen), turn
   wifi off so you're on cellular data
4. Attempt to retrieve data again (try and wait as short or as long as
   you'd like....1 second, 10 seconds, 2 minutes produce the same
   result). This should result in a failure (on the servicestack client
   it results in a timeout, on httpclients it results in an
   OperationCancelledException, which underneath it all is a timeout)
5. After attempting to retrieve data and receiving a failure on the
   first attempt, try again and you should succeed.

We prefer to use the ServiceStack clients in our application as it hides away a lot of complex code. Through research of the problem, a good amount of information points us to use a library called ModernHttpClient ( this bug describes our exact steps but is reported as relevant to iOS ), but this does not fix our issue.

A video screencast of these steps can also be found here To see a sample screencast of this watch this video https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9ulyVqWgbL3aEUzVFJEYTF2dEk .
The simple sample application used in the above screen cast can be found at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9ulyVqWgbL3UHZmX2x6NDBEY00

Do any of you know if this is an Android OS problem, a mono problem, or a code problem...or a combination of a couple of those? Is there a fix to it?

EDIT: Another scenario to try that is interesting.

1. Start the application on a phone using wifi
2. Attempt to retrieve data. This should result in a successful
   retrieval
3. Using the quick settings bar (pulling down from top of screen), turn
   wifi off so you're on cellular data
4. Enter Airplane mode
5. Exit airplane mode
6. Attempt to retrieve data again. This will result in success

Comment: It seems some connection is being held when the device changes network and is not aware of it. Can you add a *connection: close* header to the ServiceStack client? in this way you will ensure the connection is not being reused and it may avoid this problem

Comment: @Gusman I like the idea, and on the System.Net.HttpClient (PCL Version) i can add this just find. However, ServiceStack uses HttpWebRequest and when I try to add the header it throws the exception "System.ArgumentException: This header must be modified with the appropiate property". Unfortunately for me, the PCL HttpWebRequest (or at least the mono PCL version) does not expose the Connection property, or KeepAlive property of the HttpWebRequest

Comment: I think you're creating a Forms app. If that's the case then it's not very difficult to add the header (just a bit laborious). 1-Create an interface per example IHttpRequestManipulator with one public function accepting an HttpWebRequest as parameter. 2-on the android or ios project add a class which inherits from the interface and in the function set KeepAlive to false. 3-register the class as a Dependency for the Xamarin DependencyService. 4-When you need to set keepalive to false get the service from the dependency service, pass the request and it will have the keepalive changed to false

Comment: @Gusman , thank you for your reply, this worked. If I could ask you to put your answer in the answer section so I can select it as the answer to give you rep, that would be great! Again thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you @Benji, I added the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the client is reusing the connection after the change of network, and of course the connection is not valid.

You can add "content: closed" by setting KeepAlive to false to the HttpWebRequest, but from a PCL assembly cannot be done.

Thus you must create a Dependency from the PCL to the ios/android projects, send the request to the native side, set KeepAlive to false and return, in this way the connections will close and when you create a new connection it will be on the new network.

Comment: One thing to note is that with ServiceStack I am using a JsonServiceClient. There is a property on either the class, or the instance object called "RequestFilter". In order to be able to change the header of the request with the dependency service you need to be able to pass the request object to the dependencyservice. The RequestFilter 's signature is "Action<HttpWebRequest"....so you can do something like....

JsonServiceClient.RequestFilter = (request) =>{ // do stuff with request here }"